# Definition of a function error in textbook?

Tags: functions

The excerpt from my books reads:

"In a function, it's okay for two or more values of the independent variable to map to a single value of the independent variable. But it is *not* okay for a single value of the independent variable to map to two or more values of the dependent variable. A function can be *many-to-one*, but never *one-to-many*. Sometimes, in order to emphasize the fact that no value of the independent variable maps into more than one value of the dependent variable, we'll talk about this type of relation as a *true function* or a *legitimate function*"

Shouldn't the **first sentence** instead say:
"In a function, it's okay for two or more values of the independent variable to map to a single value of the <strike>independent</strike> **dependent** variable." ?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a typo in your book.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you. I was reading it very carefully, and I could only get reassurance from another opinion! To be fair it's not an official textbook, but one of those more informal instruction books....I guess it would be wise to find a formal, better edited book then...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is listed at the author's website:

[Stan Gibilisco's Correction Pages](http://www.sciencewriter.net/mistakes.htm) > [Corrections for *Calculus Know-It-All*](http://www.sciencewriter.net/calculus/) > [Page 5](http://www.sciencewriter.net/calculus/page005.png)

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even think to look up if there were any corrections online. Thank you! That's very helpful :) !